# Force children to unmount before the parent in React (hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The normal pattern goes:

- Parent mounts
- Children mounts
- Parent unmounts
- Children unmount

In my case, however, the order of the last two is a problem. The parents and children are not DOM elements. When they mount, `useEffect()` registers their existence in an external library, and the cleanup function unregisters them. In this library, the children can't exist without their parent. So, the children's cleanup must take place before the parents.

Currently my workaround is for the parent to unregister the children in its own cleanup function, but that means that other parts of the cleanup don't happen.

The only other workaround I can think of would be to use `window.setTimeout` to delay the parent's cleanup routine for "long enough", but obviously that could be a bit error prone. And likely to lead to race conditions if the parent needs to quickly be remounted etc.

Is there a way to force the children to be unmounted before the parent?

Comment: How is your workaround working? Are you manually specifying children? You can use React's Top-Level API [`React.ReactChildren`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Children) to manipulate and register child nodes and automatically force them to cleanup in your parent's cleanup function. It may be helpful to provide some minimal code to help visualize your problem.

Comment: I'm using the external library in which they are registered to find and remove them from that library.

Comment: How would I force a child to do cleanup, through the Children API?

Comment: You could use a callback prop in the children to pass a function to the parent node that will do the cleanup from above, given that the cleanup is removing the children from the library you have. This lets the parent execute code in the children.

Comment: do you have control over children? then we can use the switch

Comment: See an idea from that page [Running some code for each child](https://react.dev/reference/react/Children#running-some-code-for-each-child). You can then register each child in state, then simply "clean" all the children in state in the parent cleanup function. But I'm not sure if this is any different from what you are currently doing, since it seems you are using the external library to do something similar.

Comment: Sounds like you should fix the external library so that if a child tries to unregister when it's already been cleaned up because the parent unregistered, it just goes "k, done, there was nothing I had to do to remove this child, it was already gone"?

Comment: I think you got the order wrong, see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nqydqg?description=A%20create-react-app%20project%20based%20on%20react%20and%20react-dom&file=src%2FApp.js&title=React%20Starter)